# How to add derivatives to Hermite Interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I try to use

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{f[1]=2,f'[1]=3,f[2]=6, f'[2]=7, f''[2]=8}, Method->"Hermite"]
```

in WolframAlpha, but it's wrong.

Comment: `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{1}, 2, 3}, {{2}, 6, 7, 8}}, x]`

Comment: Thank you! You can add that as an answer I think.

Comment: Is this a wolfram alpha question, are they on topic?

Comment: Are you using the WolframAlpha website directly, or _Mathematica_? If you are using the website directly, then it is off-topic as this website is dedicated to _Mathematica_ only.

Comment: I use both of them.

Comment: @rcollyer I was in doubt also ...

Comment: @bel, can you settle this question, if you don't mind?

Comment: @J.M. Done as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{1}, 2, 3}, {{2}, 6, 7, 8}}, x]
```

In WA:

[image]

In Mathematica:

[image]